# MongoDB: group all documents that dont have their Object id inside documents in another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

so we have a sales site with a glitch that some times a buy order wont go to the shopping cart. I have the task of creating a query to find all the documents inside the orders collection, with a open status, that dont have their ObjectID inside any document, with orderState = edit, in the cart collection

Heres an exemple of a document in the orders collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5dac90c7f16568a5df67e5"),
    "shipment" : {
        "invoice" : "",
        "carrying" : "",
        "billingDate" : null,
        "shipmentDate" : null,
        "internalID" : "",
        "externalID" : ""
    },
    "version" : NumberInt(0),
    "integrated" : false,
    "splited" : false,
    "totalValue" : NumberInt(0),
    "totalQty" : NumberInt(0),
    "mainSupplierOrder" : true,
    "id" : "",
    "shop" : ObjectId("5c5d88dcb60645517cf64990"),
    "supplier" : ObjectId("5c50bca84359b945410a2c2f"),
    "status" : "open",
    "config" : {
        "discount" : NumberInt(0),
        "paymentMethod" : "",
        "operation" : "100.01",
        "obs" : "",
        "conference" : false
    },
    "products" : [

    ],
    "history" : [

    ],
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-02-08T16:21:36.644+0000"),
    "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2019-02-08T16:21:36.644+0000"),
    "lastModifiedBy" : "user.name",
    "__v" : NumberInt(0),
    "isOpen" : true
}
```

and an exemple of a document in the carts collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5de236b47d8ddf670a21e8"),
    "calc" : ObjectId("62b40160e0f39d6cf5d9e3e9"),
    "shop" : ObjectId("5c5d88dcb60645517cf64969"),
    "createdBy" : "useremail@email.com.br",
    "lastModifiedBy" : "user.name",
    "orderState" : "edit",
    "orders" : [
        ObjectId("5c5de26ab47d8ddf670a23b0"),
        ObjectId("62b1f84c2b9a7103926ab44c"),
        ObjectId("62b1f84c2b9a718e376ab449"),
        ObjectId("62b1f84c2b9a7130486ab444")
    ],
    "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2022-06-27T14:13:23.293+0000"),
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-02-08T20:10:30.460+0000"),
    "__v" : NumberInt(1)
}
```

I must find all open orders that dont have their ObjectID inside the orders field in the carts documents with the field orderState = edit

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I would say the approach I would use heavily relies on the scale of these two collections, if you could share some metrics. also how often will this thing run? is it just a one off as the bug is fixed so we can care less about efficiency?

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me with this. Both collections have around 25k documents each, the bug isnt fixed but we are working on it. I'll run this query manually probably 2 or 3 times a day.